# volume and area element

Tags: calculus

when finding the moment of inertia, we have :

$I=\int r^2 dm$

when finding the moment of intertia for a uniform disc , we use

$dm = \frac{M}{A}dA= \frac{M}{\pi R^2}2\pi rdr$

Plugging into the integral, we get

$I =\frac{2M}{R^2} \int_{0}^{R} r^3dr = \frac{1}{2}MR^2$

Which is correct, however, when finding the moment of inertia of a uniform sphere, and subbing:

$dm = \frac{M}{V}dV$ where $dV = 4\pi r^2dr$

we get :

$I =\frac{3M}{R^3} \int_{0}^{R} r^4dr = \frac{3}{5}MR^2$

which, for a sphere, is incorrect, we should get, for a sphere:

$I = \frac{2}{5}MR^2$

Thus the question is, why can we use

$dA = 2\pi rdr$

in the first example , but in the second example

$dV = 4\pi r^2dr$, fails , surely geometrically

$dA = 2\pi rdr$ is just as valid as $dV = 4\pi r^2dr$?

I like to imagine a shell with thickness $dr$ for $dV$ and a circumference with thickness $dr$ for $dA$ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The moment of inertia uses the distance *from an axis*, rather than from a point. Hence we actually look at concentric cylinders of width $dr$, which have volume approximately $ 2\pi r h \, dr$, where $h$ is the height at radius $r$, rather than concentric spheres.

For a sphere, $h=2\sqrt{R^2-r^2}$ by drawing a picture: $r$ is the distance from a chosen axis (which one doesn't matter for a sphere), not the centre of the sphere, and the cross-section parallel to the axis is a circle, and so on. One then calculates
$$ \frac{M}{4\pi R^3/3}\int_0^R r^2 \cdot 2\pi r \cdot 2\sqrt{R^2-r^2} \, dr $$
in the usual way: one may integrate by parts, for example.

Comment: Thanks very much, I see now the error